# The GRPC services exposed are not showing up in server reflection, neither it is getting listed using grpcurl

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, grpc, grpc-java

The GRPC service Implementation Code:

```
package com.nucleiassignment3.grpc;
import com.google.protobuf.Empty;
import com.mysql_crud.grpc.*;
import com.nucleiassignment3.HttpServer.bo.EmployeeBo;
import com.nucleiassignment3.HttpServer.mapper.ProtoToRequestMapper;
import com.nucleiassignment3.HttpServer.service.EmployeeService;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;    
import org.lognet.springboot.grpc.GRpcService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@GRpcService
public class EmployeeGrpcImpl extends EmployeesServiceGrpc.EmployeesServiceImplBase {
@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;
@Override
public void createEmployee(CreateEmployeeRequest request,                         StreamObserver<CreateEmployeeResponse> responseObserver) {
    EmployeeBo     employeeBo=employeeService.createEmployee(ProtoToRequestMapper.employeeRequest(request));
    java.sql.Date dob=employeeBo.getDob();
    CreateEmployeeResponse createEmployeeResponse=CreateEmployeeResponse.newBuilder()
            .setEmployee(Employee.newBuilder()
                    .setId(employeeBo.getEmpId())
                    .setName(employeeBo.getName())
                    .setDob(Date.newBuilder()
                            .setDay(dob.getDay())
                            .setMonth(dob.getMonth())
                            .setYear(dob.getYear())
                            .build())
                    .setGender(employeeBo.getGender())
                    .build())
            .build();
    responseObserver.onNext(createEmployeeResponse);
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
@Override
public void getEmployee(GetEmployeeRequest request,StreamObserver<GetEmployeeResponse> responseObserver){
    EmployeeBo employeeBo=employeeService.getEmployee(request.getId());
    GetEmployeeResponse employeeResponse=GetEmployeeResponse.newBuilder()
            .setEmployee(Employee.newBuilder()
                    .setId(employeeBo.getEmpId())
                    .setName(employeeBo.getName())
                    .setGender(employeeBo.getGender())
                    .setDob(Date.newBuilder()
                            .setDay(employeeBo.getDob().getDay())
                            .setMonth(employeeBo.getDob().getMonth())
                            .setYear(employeeBo.getDob().getYear())
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .build();
    responseObserver.onNext(employeeResponse);
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
@Override
public void listEmployees(ListEmployeesRequest request, StreamObserver<ListEmployeesResponse> responseObserver) {
}
@Override
public void updateEmployee(UpdateEmployeeRequest request,StreamObserver<UpdateEmployeeResponse> responseObserver){

}
@Override
public void deleteEmployee(DeleteEmployeeRequest request, StreamObserver<Empty>     responseObserver) {
}
}
```

Application.yml File :

```
 spring:
    datasource:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****'
      username: root
      password: ******
  jpa:
   show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
  properties:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
  server:
    port: '9191'
  grpc:
    port: '8080'
    enableReflection: true
```

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.2"
    }

group = 'com.nucleiassignment3'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus"
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final"
annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final"
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
implementation group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '3.21.12'
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-all', version: '1.53.0'
implementation group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protoc', version: '3.21.12', ext:     'pom'
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
implementation 'io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:5.0.0'
}
sourceSets {
main {
    proto {
        srcDirs 'src/main/resources/proto'
    }
    java {
        srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
        srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
    }
}
}
protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
}
plugins {
    grpc {
        artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.0-pre2'
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
        grpc {}
    }
}
}
```

The grpc services defined are not getting exposed in the server relection. I tried all the possible solutions, but could not find the issue. I used postman for grpc calls, but the methods are not showing up in the server reflection. The grpcurl list command also doesnt list the services/methods defined. Please help, it would be highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Tried Implementing GRPC and Rest Api for CRUD operation on MySql Database, using JPA.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Please post the ‘@SpringBootApplication class including it’s package.

Comment: @EricAnderson The Grpc server is not starting itself, only the tomcat server is starting.

Comment: The SpringBootApplication
    package com.nucleiassignment3.HttpServer;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class HttpServerApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(HttpServerApplication.class, args);
 }

    }

Comment: @EricAnderson I got it, the grpc service implementation, was in a different package, so it was not catching. Thanks a lot, but another problem is that the services exposed, is not showing in server reflection. If you could help with that, it would be highly helpful

Comment: The grpc services is working fine when calling by creating a client, but I want to expose services, and its not working. I know the services are working fine, as when I am calling from a client, its working fine, but when using Postman, the methods are not getting exposed.